# Redirect user to the phone app with a phone number composed, without starting the call

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view in my iOS app that displays information about a certain pet in our database (name, breed, age, image, etc.), and this info includes the owner's phone number.

What I want to add to this view is a button that opens the phone app and composes / dials the owner's phone number **without actually starting the call**, i.e. user starts the call manually but the number is shown on screen programmatically.

I tried using the following piece of code (opening a tel:// URI), but it automatically starts the call.

`UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "tel://" + "00000000".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

("00000000" here is just a dummy phone number for illustration purposes).

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to show the number in the phone app, without starting the call?

Comment: What if user presses the button accidentally? They would not want a call to start directly.

Comment: And I know that using a pop-up to confirm before calling should work, but I'd prefer it if I can do it without a pop-up.

Comment: When your app opens a Tel URI, iOS prompts the user to confirm that they want to place the call. If they don't they just tap "cancel". You can't avoid this pop up and you don't need to create your own

Comment: @Paulw11 this was introduced in iOS 10.3 if I am not mistaken. In iOS versions prior to that, the app directly calls the phone number (I tested it).

Comment: Display your own dialog on prior to iOS 10 (or target iOS 10+; very few devices run earlier than iOS 10). What is a better UX? The user taps cancel and gets to stay in your app or the user is switched to the phone app when they didn't want to.  Also, consider iOS 10+ (the vast majority of users) they would need to tap "ok" on the iOS dialog and then tap "call" in the actual phone app (3 taps including the original number tap)

Comment: @Paulw11 well, I guess you're right, thanks for your feedback! I will most probably go for what you said.